# Вывод цветного кириллического текста

Tags: c, visual-c++

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma hdrstop
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma argsused
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void OEMTextOut(char *Buffer, int TextAttribute = 10)
{ // Вывод цветного кириллического текста
    char outBuffer[256];
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, TextAttribute);
    CharToOemA(Buffer, outBuffer); // кириллизация текста
    printf_s("%s\n", outBuffer); // вывод текста
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    OEMTextOut("=== SimpleHandler ===", 11);
    OEMTextOut("Начало", 12);
    try {
        OEMTextOut(" ...в блоке try");
        OEMTextOut(" Генерация текстового исключения 'Это тест!'", 14);
        throw " Это тест!"; // генерация исключения, заданного постоянной строкового типа
        OEMTextOut("Эта строка не отобразится, т.к. управление передано блоку catch");
    }
    catch (const char* p) { // перехват исключения, заданного постоянной строкового типа
        OEMTextOut(" ...в блоке catch");
        // преобразование постоянного указателя на строку в переменный
        OEMTextOut(const_cast <char *> (p), 14);
    }
    OEMTextOut("Конец", 12);
    system("pause");
}
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

> Ошибка    C2664 "BOOL CharToOemW(LPCWSTR,LPSTR)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "char *" в "LPCWSTR"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый аргумент `CharToOemW` должен быть юникодной строкой.

Comment: Аргуменет чего?

Comment: @Cerbo, `CharToOemW`.

Comment: На всякий случай, ничего плохого своим коментарием я не имел в виду :)))

Comment: Так что мне сделать? Я просто не могу понять.

Comment: @JZ_52, использовать `CharToOemA`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо что отредактировал пост и я не сразу заметил разницу в написании.

Comment: @Qwertiy, CharToOemW не работает, а вот с А работает, но не выводит текст((